# Excel VBA - loop through spreadsheet creating tables based on query

Tags: vba, excel

I'm hoping to loop through a worksheet and create Tables based on certain indexes. Essentially my table is structured as follows:

```
ID | 101
Date | 2018-07-18
Product | Banana
Comments | 

ID | 102
Date | 2018-07-18
Product | Apple
Comments |
```

And I'm just hoping to write a code that will loop through the worksheet and make one Table for every ID to Comments. I'm included links to screenshots showing my initial table, and the desired outcome of the code.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have written so far.

Comment: These look nearly the same except there is one extra header above and in between the two blocks. Is that the only difference?

Comment: Try using the Macro Recorder to get you started. It writes terrible, but functional code. Once you have something that works once, you can attempt to put it in a loop and come back to ask a very specific question.

Comment: Do you want a table for every instance of ID?

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. @PGCodeRider you are correct I want a table (ListObjects.Add) for every instance of ID.

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, but this seems to be a very bad design overall. Especially when I see your other comment saying you want to eventually pass each table through to PowerQuery. I don't know the final goal here, but you might be better off transforming the output somehow to be more relational. Maybe convert each 4-row sub-table into a single row then make one table of the whole thing. Something along those lines would allow for easier maintenance / growth too. Just my 2 cents....

Comment: Thanks for your comment @John Bustos. I'm basically converting pages of a report into database format. My strategy (only because this is how I have been doing it manually) is to make each data table into a Table object, send each table into Power Query, unipivot each data table using this M code (https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/06/19/unpivot-by-number-of-columns-and-rows-in-powerbi-and-powerquery-in-excel/), and then appending every single table (now that they have been processed to have the same format). Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: William, again, I don't know the scope of your project, but it may make more sense to just write a good looping program in VBA to unpivot and normalize the data for you form the get-go, but without knowing more, I can't promise that's the best way to go - Just based upon what you're saying, I think that's the way I would go. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a highly customized solution. It assumes table always 4 rows and two columns.

```
Sub easyGoofy()
Dim WS As Worksheet, rCell As Range, i As Integer, rStart As Long

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
i = 0
rStart = 1

startSearch:
    If Not Intersect(WS.UsedRange.Cells, WS.Rows(rStart & ":" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then

        For Each rCell In Intersect(WS.UsedRange.Cells, WS.Rows(rStart & ":" & Rows.Count)).Cells
            If UCase(rCell.Value) = "ID" And UCase(rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) = "DATE" Then

                WS.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(rCell, rCell.Offset(3, 1)), , xlYes).Name = "TBL_" & i
                rStart = WS.ListObjects("TBL_" & i).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1 + rStart
                 i = i + 1

                GoTo startSearch

            End If
        Next rCell

    End If

Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is definitely what I was looking for. However, when I run this code, the first table (first instance of ID) successfully generates but then it throws a runtime error 1004: a table cannot overlap another table. It seems like Excel is not moving on to the next ID but is rather trying to generate another table on top of the first one. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @William I updated code to avoid the crossover of tables. Assuming this works, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @PGCodeRider, unfortunately this is still throwing the same runtime 1004 error. Wish I knew more to try to debug the code. I was also looking into trying to use the FIND function to identify the starting and ending row numbers (every table starts with a cell in column A containing "ID" and ends with a cell in column A containing "Comments"), since the tables are not necessarily all 4 rows tall...but I still can't figure out how to write the code.

Comment: @William Do you need headers? (i.e. COlumn1 and column2?)

Comment: I don't think so; my next step is to pass each Table object into Power Query, which is another question for another day, but yeah I don't think I need headers for that; so long as the entire contents of the target range is in the body of the output Table object, it should work fine.

Comment: @William I updated the code to not have headers. Assuming the rows and columns match your example consistently, that should always work.

Comment: Thanks @PGCodeRider, code runs great! Thanks for getting me started, now I just have to figure out how to calculate the size of the table (since it won't always be 4 rows tall). Question for next time.